# allowing only pdf files to be uploaded

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a browse button in my windows form application and i wanted to only filter down to the option of choosing pdf files. So in the browse file window only pdf files will be visible and not showing .doc or any kind of document format.

```
private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        var res = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DocumentUNCPath.Text = dlg.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  See answer here along with explaination. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069048/setting-the-filter-to-an-openfiledialog-to-allow-the-typical-image-formats

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly you need to apply a filter first to the `OpenFileDialog` such as:

```
dlg.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf";
```

However, that doesn't stop them from forcing through a file (which they can do). You can again check the filename again after they click on OK but this is no guarantee that the file you get will be a PDF.

To be safe you could use a PDF library either locally or server side to try and open the PDF file and see if it really is such.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
dlg.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf";
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set the filter property on your `dlg` object like this:

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "*.pdf";
var res = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (res == DialogResult.OK)
{
    DocumentUNCPath.Text = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189944%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
dlg.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf"
```

The portion to the left of the `|` can be anything, I just gave you an example, but it's what's shown to the user. The portion to the right of the `|` is the actual Windows filter.