# How HTML & CSS Code Can Be Used to Print POS on vb.net

Tags: html, css, vb.net, webbrowser-control, webview2

I tried printing from HTML and CSS on a printer with the program language vb.net.

Please Guide Me

one more I want to add QR in footer section

This My code :

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Function ToHtml() As String
        Dim Pathimageheader As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logo.png")
        Dim Pathimagefooter As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Qr.png")
        Dim html =
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
                    <title>Receipt example</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
                </head>
                <style>
                {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
td,
th,
tr,
table {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.description,
th.description {
    width: 75px;
    max-width: 75px;
}

td.quantity,
th.quantity {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

td.price,
th.price {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.ticket {
    width: 155px;
    max-width: 155px;
}

img {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
</style>
                <body>
                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src=<%= Pathimageheader %> alt="logo"></img>
                        <p class="centered">RECEIPT EXAMPLE
                        <br>Address line 1
                        </br><br>Address line2</br></p>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="quantity">Q.</th>
                                    <th class="description">Description</th>
                                    <th class="price">$$</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="quantity">1.00</td>
                                    <td class="description">ARDUINO UNO R3</td>
                                    <td class="price">$25.00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="quantity">2.00</td>
                                    <td class="description">JAVASCRIPT BOOK</td>
                                    <td class="price">$10.00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="quantity">1.00</td>
                                    <td class="description">STICKER PACK</td>
                                    <td class="price">$10.00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="quantity"></td>
                                    <td class="description">TOTAL</td>
                                    <td class="price">$55.00</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <p class="centered">Thanks for your purchase!
                             <br>parzibyte.me/blog</br></p>
                        <img src=<%= Pathimagefooter %> alt="logo"></img>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>

        Return html.ToString()
    End Function
 Private Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click
    
        myWebBrowser.DocumentText = ToHtml()

    End Sub
 Private Sub myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted
        myWebBrowser.Parent = Me
        myWebBrowser.Visible = False
        myWebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
    End Sub
```

Desired result (without botton)

sorry I can't post the original html and css code because of an error at the time of posting but below is the link of the html and css code

[link](https://parzibyte.me/blog/en/2019/10/10/print-receipt-thermal-printer-javascript-css-html/)

[image]

[image]

result after update code

[image: result after update code]

RESULT AFTER UPDATE CODE LATEST

[image: RESULT AFTER UPDATE CODE LATEST]

[image: RESULT FROM ANSWER]

[image: Qrcode.png]

print screen dialog

[image: print screen dialog]

Comment: You need to include the CSS code in the HTML or add link to external CSS file. Both must be enclosed in <head> element container to enclose the CSS code in `<style>` element or link external CSS file using the `<link>` element. For the first option, you've been told how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381209/14171304). Benefit from your previous questions. For the QR, use the `<img src="somePath">`.

Comment: @dr.null , 
Thank you for your suggestion, I have updated the post for the code CSS . 
thank you for your advice, I have updated the post for the code but for the html header section along with the image and footer along with the QR image I still have an error, please guide me

Comment: What error? Speak out! You forgot to include the `<div class="ticket">` part in that link. For the image, it won't draw itself. You need to have that logo saved somewhere in your disk and use the `<img src="TheImagePath">` element. The same for the footer.

Comment: @dr.null , `You forgot to include the <div class="ticket"> part in that link.` 
if this is already in the code that I posted. Error for line `<img src="Pathimageheader"> Element is missing an end tag` and `<p class="centered">Thanks for your purchase!</p> Expected beginning '<' for an XML tag, XML name expected, '>' expected`

Comment: `<img src=<%= Pathimageheader %> alt="logo"></img>` or just `<img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></img>`.

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your advice . so I use this `<img src=<%= Pathimageheader %> alt="logo"></img>` 
if I use this `<img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></img>` then the image doesn't come out.  
I have an error in this code `<br>Address line 1 <br>Address line 2</p>`  
error like this `Element is missing an end tag , Expected beginning '<' for an XML tag, XML name expected`

Comment: `<p class="centered">RECEIPT EXAMPLE<br>Address line 1</br><br>Address line2</br></p>`.

Comment: @dr.null , Thank you for your response, but there are still things that are not correct, like what I posted, there are 3 blue markings and I have also posted the code. Please guide me

Comment: In the `td.price, th.price` style, increase the `width:` and `max-width:` values. As for the vertical space if you mean that, see [How to change the height of a <br>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#remarks) control is quite old and may not support some of the newer styling. You may consider using the [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control instead. Also, it appears that you've included style information twice - once as a link to a Style Sheet, and a second time in the HTML.

The following shows how to use JavaScript, CSS, and HTML to create a receipt in VB.NET. It's an implementation of the code referenced in the OP - [Print receipt in thermal printer using JavaScript, CSS & HTML](https://parzibyte.me/blog/en/2019/10/10/print-receipt-thermal-printer-javascript-css-html/). The code below uses NuGet package [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) to display the receipt. See the comments throughout the code for more information.

**VS 2022**:

**Create a new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) project**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Download/install NuGet package**: Microsoft.Web.WebView2

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> and select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse** tab
- Search for **Microsoft.Web.WebView2**
- Click **Install**

**Create Templates folder**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Folder...**
- Rename folder: **Templates**

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Add logo image to Templates folder**: (name: logo.png)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Templates**
- Select **Add**
- Select **Existing Item...**
- In the drop-down (lower-right) change the filter to Image Files(...) and select your logo image (ex: logo.png)
- In Solution Explorer, under the **Templates** folder, select the logo image (ex: logo.png)
- In the Properties Window, set **Build Action: Content** and **Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always**

**Add QR code image to Templates folder**: (name: qrCode.jpg)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Templates**
- Select **Add**
- Select **Existing Item...**
- In the drop-down (lower-right) change the filter to Image Files(...) and select your logo image (ex: qrCode.jpg)
- In Solution Explorer, under the **Templates** folder, select the QR code image (ex: qrCode.jpg)
- In the Properties Window, set **Build Action: Content** and **Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always**

**Note**: If you'd like to generate a QR code programmatically, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75061787/10024425).

**Add Style Sheet to Templates folder**: (name: style.css)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Templates**
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- On left side expand **Common Items**. Then click **Web**.
- Select **Style Sheet** (name: style.css)
- In the Properties Window, set **Build Action: Content** and **Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always**

**style.css**:

```
* {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}

td,
th,
tr,
table {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

    td.description,
    th.description {
        width: 75px;
        max-width: 75px;
    }

    td.quantity,
    th.quantity {
        width: 40px;
        max-width: 40px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    td.price,
    th.price {
        width: 40px;
        max-width: 40px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.ticket {
    width: 155px;
    max-width: 155px;
}

img {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

@media print {
    .hidden-print,
    .hidden-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

**Add JavaScript file to Templates folder**: (name: printReceipt.js)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Templates**
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- On left side expand **Common Items**. Then click **Web**.
- Select **JavaScript File** (name: printReceipt.js)
- In the Properties Window, set **Build Action: Content** and **Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always**

**printReceipt.js**:

```
const $btnPrint = document.querySelector("#btnPrint");
$btnPrint.addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.print();
});
```

**Add receipt.html to Templates folder**:

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Templates**
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- On left side expand **Common Items**. Then click **Web**.
- Select **HTML Page** (name: receipt.html)
- In the Properties Window, set **Build Action: Content** and **Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always**

**Note**: In the HTML, I've removed the table data, and replaced it with a placeholder ("rowsPlaceHolder"). In VB.NET, we'll generate the HTML that goes here, and replace "rowsPlaceHolder" with the HTML. The paths for the style sheet and JavaScript file are relative to this HTML file, so either change the paths as necessary, or ensure that the HTML file is in the same folder as the style sheet (.css) and JavaScript file (.js).

**receipt.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Receipt example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ticket">
        <img src="./logo.png" alt="Logo">
        <p class="centered">
            RECEIPT EXAMPLE
            <br>Address line 1
            <br>Address line 2
        </p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="quantity">Q.</th>
                    <th class="description">Description</th>
                    <th class="price">$$</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                rowsPlaceHolder
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p class="centered">
            Thanks for your purchase!
            <br />
            <img src="qrCode.jpg" alt="QRCode" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <button id="btnPrint" class="hidden-print">Print</button>
    <script src="printReceipt.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Solution Explorer, you should see the following:

[image]

---

**Add a Form to the project** (name: FrmReceipt.vb)

**Note**: This form will host the [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) browser control which will display the receipt.

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- On left side click **Common Items**.
- Select **Form (Windows Form)** (name: FrmReceipt.vb)
- Double-click the form to add the *Load* event handler
- Resize the form as desired

**Open the Toolbox**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**

**Add WebView2 to FrmReceipt** (name: webView21)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **FrmReceipt.vb** and select **View Designer**.
- In the Toolbox, scroll to the top and expand **WebView2 Windows Forms Control**
- Drag **WebView2** control onto FrmReceipt
- On the form, click the WebView2 control to select it
- In the Properties Window, set **Dock: Fill**

**FrmReceipt.vb**:

**Note**: In the code below, you'll notice that the *async* keyword has been added to the *Load* event handler.

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms

Public Class FrmReceipt

    Private appTempFolder As String = String.Empty
    Private receiptFilename As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(receiptFilename As String)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.receiptFilename = receiptFilename

        'set value
        appTempFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(receiptFilename)
        Debug.WriteLine($"FrmReceipt appTempFolder: {appTempFolder}")
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub FrmReceipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Debug.WriteLine($"WebView2 version: {GetWebView2Version()}")

        'set UserDataFolder
        WebView21.CreationProperties = New CoreWebView2CreationProperties() With {.UserDataFolder = appTempFolder}

        'explicitly initialize CoreWebView2
        Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()

        'display receipt
        WebView21.Source = New Uri($"file:///{receiptFilename}")
    End Sub

    Public Function GetWebView2Version() As String
        Dim webView2Assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = GetType(WebView2).Assembly
        Return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(webView2Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
    End Function
End Class
```

---

One can use the following to generate the receipt:

**Note**: The code below will go in the main form (ex: Form1.vb). If desired one can rename *Form1.vb* to something such as *FrmMain.vb*.

```
Private appTempFolder As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
Private templatesFolder As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Templates")
Private addressLine1 As String = "123 Walnut Street"
Private addressLine2 As String = "Some City, ABC 12345"

Private Sub CreateReceipt()
    'for testing, we'll create a folder in the user's temp folder
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(appTempFolder) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(appTempFolder)
    End If

    'copy the following files so that they exist in the same folder as the .html file
    System.IO.File.Copy(System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesFolder, "logo.png"), System.IO.Path.Combine(appTempFolder, "logo.png"), True)
    System.IO.File.Copy(System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesFolder, "printReceipt.js"), System.IO.Path.Combine(appTempFolder, "printReceipt.js"), True)
    System.IO.File.Copy(System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesFolder, "qrCode.jpg"), System.IO.Path.Combine(appTempFolder, "qrCode.jpg"), True)
    System.IO.File.Copy(System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesFolder, "style.css"), System.IO.Path.Combine(appTempFolder, "style.css"), True)

    'get data
    'here a method is used to generate test data
    'but one could get data from a database instead
    Dim dt As DataTable = CreateTestData()

    'HTML filename
    Dim receiptFilename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(appTempFolder, "receipt.html")

    'generate HTML and save to file
    GenerateHtml(dt, receiptFilename)

    'display receipt
    Dim receipt As FrmReceipt = New FrmReceipt(receiptFilename)
    receipt.Show()
End Sub

Private Function CreateTestData() As DataTable
    'create new instance
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Items")

    'Add column: Qty
    Dim quantity As DataColumn = New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Qty", .DataType = GetType(Double)}
    dt.Columns.Add(quantity)

    'Add column: Description
    Dim description As DataColumn = New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Description", .DataType = GetType(String)}
    dt.Columns.Add(description)

    'Add column: Price
    Dim price As DataColumn = New DataColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Price", .DataType = GetType(Decimal)}
    dt.Columns.Add(price)

    Dim row As DataRow = Nothing

    row = dt.NewRow() 'create new row
    row("Qty") = 1
    row("Description") = "ARDUINO UNO R3"
    row("Price") = 25
    dt.Rows.Add(row) 'add to DataTable

    row = dt.NewRow() 'create new row
    row("Qty") = 2
    row("Description") = "JAVASCRIPT BOOK"
    row("Price") = 10
    dt.Rows.Add(row) 'add to DataTable

    row = dt.NewRow() 'create new row
    row("Qty") = 2
    row("Description") = "JAVASCRIPT BOOK"
    row("Price") = 10
    dt.Rows.Add(row) 'add to DataTable

    row = dt.NewRow() 'create new row
    row("Qty") = 1
    row("Description") = "STICKER PACK"
    row("Price") = 10
    dt.Rows.Add(row) 'add to DataTable

    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub GenerateHtml(dt As DataTable, outputFilename As String)

    'get HTML from template
    Dim html As String = File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesFolder, "receipt.html"))
    Dim itemsHtml As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim total As Decimal = 0

    'create HTML for each item
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        'create HTML for each row
        itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(16)}<tr>{System.Environment.NewLine}")

        'convert to double
        Dim quantity As Double = 0
        Double.TryParse(dt(i)("Qty").ToString(), quantity)

        'convert to decimal
        Dim price As Decimal = 0
        Decimal.TryParse(dt(i)("Price").ToString(), price)

        'add data to table column
        itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(20)}<td class = ""quantity"">{quantity.ToString("N2")}</td>{System.Environment.NewLine}")
        itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(20)}<td class = ""description"">{dt(i)("Description")}</td>{System.Environment.NewLine}")
        itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(20)}<td class = ""price"">{price.ToString("N2")}</td>{System.Environment.NewLine}")

        itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(16)}</tr>{System.Environment.NewLine}")

        'add
        total += price
    Next

    'add HTML for Total
    itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(16)}<tr>{System.Environment.NewLine}")

    itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(20)}<td class = ""quantity""></td>{System.Environment.NewLine}")
    itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(20)}<td class = ""description"">TOTAL</td>{System.Environment.NewLine}")
    itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(20)}<td class = ""price"">${total.ToString("N2")}</td>{System.Environment.NewLine}")

    itemsHtml.AppendFormat($"{Space(16)}</tr>{System.Environment.NewLine}")

    'replace address
    html = html.Replace("Address line 1", addressLine1)
    html = html.Replace("Address line 2", addressLine2)

    'replace place holder with HTML for items
    html = html.Replace("rowsPlaceHolder", itemsHtml.ToString())

    'save
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, html)
End Sub

Private Function Space(numSpaces As Integer) As String
    Return New String(" ", numSpaces)
End Function
```

**Usage**:

```
CreateReceipt()
```

---

**Update**:

If one needs to adjust the size of an image, one can use MS Paint to resize the image prior to adding it to the *Templates* folder or one can use the *width* and *height* properties of the [img tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) in the HTML to specify the desired size. When setting these properties in the HTML, the width and height should be less than or equal to the width and height of the image.

```
<img src="qrCode.jpg" alt="QRCode" width="75" height="75" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have an error `Error BC30109 'FrmReceipt' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.`  if I comment out the code from this line of code `Public Sub New(receiptFilename As String) End Sub`  
then the error is gone, please guide me

Comment: @siwa86: The code in this post has been tested, so I'm not sure why you've encountered an error. It may not have been clear where the methods such as _CreateReceipt, GenerateHtml, etc..._ should be placed. I added a note above the code block.

Comment: @siwa86: I read through the post and re-created the project following the steps in this post. I added a few more details. If the code doesn't work, you may consider creating a new project, and go step by step and try again.

Comment: sorry earlier the problem was because all the code was in 1 form but now it is working perfectly your code but just the image `QrCode.png` from  getting very big in webwiew2

Comment: @siwa86: If you click on _edited_ (below the post), then click the _Side-by-side_ tab, the changes that were made to the post will be highlighted

Comment: why does the `qrCode.png` image become very large in webview2, I have attached it to the post.

Comment: @siwa86: I've added information about image size to the end of the post.

Comment: your updates make it very perfect . btw `printReceipt.js` 
Can this be used to do printdialog or print?

Comment: @siwa86: I didn't write the JavaScript code, it's from the article that you referenced in the OP. Guess you'll have to click the button and see what happens.

Comment: You may try searching `javascript window.print`. The following may be of interest:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

Comment: I tried clicking the javascript button but there was no action

Comment: Do you have a printer installed on your computer? Ensure that the name of the JavaScript file matches the name in the HTML file. Also, ensure that the JavaScript file exists in the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: why For the size of the print screen dialog, the size becomes small, you can see in my post

Comment: thank you for your perfect answer, for the problem `window.print size` maybe I can find a solution or make a new post.

Comment: @siwa86: The Epson LX350 is a dot matrix printer. If one prints the receipt, one sees that it's rather small - it was designed to print to a thermal receipt printer such as [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=zebra+thermal+receipt+printer).

Comment: If it's not a requirement to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, then the following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562125/10024425

Comment: `: The Epson LX350 is a dot matrix printer. If one prints the receipt, one sees that it's rather small - it was designed to print to a thermal receipt printer such as these` 
I use this for a 58mm mini thermal printer . 
what I mean is the size of the print dialog `window.print()` .

Comment: `If it's not a requirement to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, then the following may be of interest: stackoverflow.com/a/71562125/10024425` but I'm more interested use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in vb.net. BTW can you give me a link or info for webview2 for direct printing