# Create QRCode with C# and save it as an image

Tags: c#, reactjs, qr-code, zxing

I'm receiving data from a URL on our web application that's  dynamically generated using an API's response. I have to handle it by putting it in a `QRCode` and send this QRCode back to the front-end for my client to download it. We're using C# for back-end and React.js for the front-end.

I've tried to use `ZXIng` libraries for C# but with no success. I've tried a lot of code, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Might want to check this out, first result for googling "c# create qr code png" https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/tutorials/csharp-qr-code-generator/

Comment: `I've tried with no success` and `I've tried a lot of codes` isn't a problem description. We can't guess what you tried or what failed. If you search for QR in NuGet you'll find a lot of packages. ZXing.NET has 11M downloads and include sample clients [like this command-line client](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/7f6f38ea676932ec497a15cf12556f55bc5ee1ea/Clients/CommandLineEncoder/Program.cs) that encodes data into any supported barcode format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. It's been tested, but you may need to adapt it for your usage which shouldn't be too difficult.

**Download/install NuGet package: `ZXing.Net`** (version: 0.16.8)

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.IO;`
- `using ZXing;`
- `using ZXing.Common;`
- `using ZXing.QrCode;`

**Code**:

```
private Bitmap CreateQrCode(string data)
{
    //specify desired options
    QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions()
    {
        CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
        DisableECI = true,
        Width = 250,
        Height = 250
    };

    //create new instance and set properties
    BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter()
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
        Options = options
    };

    //create QR code and return Bitmap
    return writer.Write(data);
}

private byte[] GetQrCodeBytes(string data, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imgFormat)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //create QR code and save to file
        using (Bitmap bmp = CreateQrCode(data))
        {
            //save to MemoryStream
            bmp.Save(ms, imgFormat);
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

private string GetTextFromQrCode(byte[] qrcodeBytes)
{
    //specify desired options
    DecodingOptions options = new DecodingOptions()
    {
        CharacterSet = "UTF-8"
    };

    //create new instance and set properties
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader() { Options = options };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(qrcodeBytes))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms))
        {
            //decode QR code
            Result r = reader.Decode(bmp);

            //return QR code text
            return r.Text;
        }
    }
}

private string GetTextFromQrCode(string filename)
{
    //specify desired options
    DecodingOptions options = new DecodingOptions()
    {
        CharacterSet = "UTF-8"
    };

    //create new instance and set properties
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader() { Options = options };

    //read image and convert to Bitmap
    using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filename))
    {
        //decode QR code
        Result r = reader.Decode(bmp);

        //return QR code text
        return r.Text;
    }
}

private void SaveQrCode(string data, string filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imgFormat)
{
    //create QR code and save to file
    using (Bitmap bmp = CreateQrCode(data))
    {
        bmp.Save(filename, imgFormat);
    }
}
```

---

**Decode QR Code** (Usage 1):

```
string filename = @"C:\Temp\TestQrCode.png"
string qrcodeText = GetTextFromQrCode(filename);
```

**Decode QR Code** (Usage 2):

**Note**: In the code below, the QR code is read from a file and placed in a `byte[]`. Reading from a file is for demonstration/testing purposes.

```
string filename = @"C:\Temp\TestQrCode.png"
byte[] qrcodeBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
string qrcodeText = GetTextFromQrCode(qrcodeBytes);
```

---

**Save QR Code** (Usage 1):

```
string qrcodeText = "This is a test";
string filename = @"C:\Temp\TestQrCode.png"

//get filename extension
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

if (ext == ".bmp" || ext == ".dib" || ext == ".rle")
    SaveQrCode(qrcodeText, filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
else if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jfif" || ext == ".jpe")
    SaveQrCode(qrcodeText, fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
else if (ext == ".png")
    SaveQrCode(qrcodeText, fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

**Save QR Code** (Usage 2):

**Note**: In the code below, the QR code is saved to a `byte[]`, then written to a file. Writing to a file is for demonstration/testing purposes.

```
string qrcodeText = "This is a test";
string filename = @"C:\Temp\TestQrCode.png"

//get filename extension
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

byte[] qrcodeBytes = null;

if (ext == ".bmp" || ext == ".dib" || ext == ".rle")
    qrcodeBytes = GetQrCodeBytes(qrcodeText, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
else if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jfif" || ext == ".jpe")
    qrcodeBytes = GetQrCodeBytes(qrcodeText, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
else if (ext == ".png")
    qrcodeBytes = GetQrCodeBytes(qrcodeText, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

//save to file
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, qrcodeBytes);
```

---

**Resources**

- [How to read and create barcode images using C# and ZXing.NET](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/how-to-read-and-create-barcode-images-using-c-and-zxing-net/)
- [Basic with QR Code using Zxing Library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005081/Basic-with-QR-Code-using-Zxing-Library)
- [Setting the filter to an OpenFileDialog to allow the typical image formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069048/setting-the-filter-to-an-openfiledialog-to-allow-the-typical-image-formats)